# why does this negative lookahead not work?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

Both of the following produce the string gotcha. why?

```
perl -e 'print "gotcha\n" if "corecaptured" =~ /(?!corecaptured)/;'

perl -e 'print "gotcha\n" if "corecaptured" =~ /(?=corecaptured)/;'
```

I expect the first not to print anything as the negative lookahead should produce a false result but I'm obviously missing something.

when I stick the regex into a debugger I get unexpected results:
https://regex101.com/r/eM4tF1/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexes are not anchored. The first condition really says "is there a position in the string `"corecaptured"` that is not followed by the text `corecaptured`?".

The answer to that is yes, because at offset 1 the following string is `"orecaptured"`, which does not start with `c`. That's why the regex match returns true.

You probably meant `/^(?!corecaptured)/`, which checks whether the target string does not start with `corecaptured`.

---

As for your regex101 link, that contains a very different regex: `a(?!b)c` is equivalent to `ac` because `(?!b)c` means "match `c` at a position where the next character is not `b`" (or in other words, "match a `c` that is not also a `b`").

If you [change it to what's in your code](https://regex101.com/r/kuzs6v/1), you'll see that the result is a single successful match (of length 0) at offset 1:

```
corecaptured
 ^
```

Comment: Or maybe they wanted `/^((?!corecaputered).)*\z/s`, which ensures that no position starts with `corecaputered`, which is to say the string doesn't contain `corecaputered`. (`!/corecaptured/` would be far more efficient, but `((?!corecaputered).)*` can be used inside a large pattern